# Android : ScreenSize Support for 8 and 7 inch screen

Tags: android, android-layout, android-screen-support

I have a problem which I`m unable to solve lately..

I have make a simple app for tablet which I run in my Samsung Galaxy Note 8.0 .. I have set the layout to place some text view at some place.. I code it in xml using dp for margin and sp for text size. The width and height layout is set to wrapcontent. But when I run it in my friend Samsung Galaxy Tab 2 7.0, the layout did not match what I see in my device. The same thing happen when I try to run it in 10inch emulator.

I have use layout-sw600dp for my layout folder..

Why my screen layout is like that?I though by using layout-sw600dp the layout supposedly to adjust itself.. Or am I wrong regarding that?

I have read android documentation regarding different screensize support and so far I found using layout-sw600dp is good solution..

I have checked the device dpi using :

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
           DisplayMetrics outMetrics = new DisplayMetrics ();
            display.getMetrics(outMetrics);

            float density  = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
            float dpHeight = outMetrics.heightPixels / density;
            float dpWidth  = outMetrics.widthPixels / density;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every device has different pixel ratio, different dpi, different screen size and so on. Go to this link, read it, you will know how to manage different device layouts.

[Android - Supporting Multiple Screen](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

Comment: I have read it a few times.. What I understand is I need to provide different layout for different sizes.. but do I really need to provide different layout for 7 and 8 inch screen?In my xml I use layout_margin with 100dp (example)..

Comment: @iwalyfa - Everything matters, check the device's dpi,.,.if they are different, then you need different layout folders, check the pixel ratio,everything matters when it comes to android layouts

Comment: I have edit my post.. I have check the device dpi.. Do I need different layout in my case?When I think about it, that`s means I need to provide a lot of layout for different screen size out there..

Comment: Yes, this is actually a headache, many 7 inch devices may have different dpi so layout changes happens,.,try to make some folders for layouts for devices on which you believe your app will work,.if you decompile popular apps, you will see many layout folders

Comment: I see.. Thanks for your advice.. I guess I have to make a few layout at least for some different screen size.. Last question, does make many layout make the app became slower?

Comment: no,.xml layout file are static files and they take very less memory space.,.so dont worry about your app being slow

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check the screen inch size when the app start, you can calculate the inch with the following two methods, but I think the second one is more precisely.

```
public static float getScreenInchSizeByDensityDpi(Context context) {
    DisplayMetrics dm = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    double x = Math.pow((double)dm.widthPixels / (double)dm.densityDpi, 2);
    double y = Math.pow((double)dm.heightPixels / (double)dm.densityDpi, 2);
    double screenInches = Math.sqrt(x + y);

    return (float) screenInches;
}

public static float getScreenInchSizeByXYDpi(Context context) {
    DisplayMetrics dm = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    double x = Math.pow((double)dm.widthPixels / (double)dm.xdpi, 2);
    double y = Math.pow((double)dm.heightPixels / (double)dm.ydpi, 2);
    double screenInches = Math.sqrt(x + y);

    return (float) screenInches;
}
```